# How to organize two api calls when clicking save button in the formik form

Tags: reactjs, api, async-await, formik

Let's say we have one form with the save button. One patch api call to save most of fields filled by users when clicking save button. However, we have one checkbox field in the form which needs another api to check the user permission and also save the selection from the user when clicking the save button along with other fields.

For example:

Sequence 1 PATCH api/1

•   If this API calls successfully, then update some fields to database. Then continue to call sequence 2 API

Sequence 2 PATCH api/2

•   If this API call return an error, then stop calling the next API, and UI returns an error/warning message. Indicates unsuccessful update & save, this misled user because a portion of data has already been saved to database.

•   Also, in some fields once value has already been updated to the database. UI will update screen to read-only mode to prevent user updating those fields. This could lead to confusion if there is warning message in UI that indicates unsuccessful update & save.

Sequence 3 PATCH api/3

Comment: Hello Yang, just some questions: what is exactly that you find difficult in this operation? The error handling, chaining the api calls or something else? Do you have some code that you tried to do and can share it? Knowing this will make it easier to help you

Comment: Thanks @Drago96, i cannot share my codes as this is kind of at the design stage when I disscussed with BA and back-end dev. The main problem for me is I don't know which is the best way to call these two apis and how I can know that which validation error is coming from which api if i am chaining the api calls.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to handle this, would be using async-await inside the `handleSave` function somewhat like this pseudo-javascript code:

```
const handleSave = async () => {

    // First API call related to the checkbox
    let response = await fetch("apiroute/first-call", { /* ... */ });
    
    // Check if the api call has given an error (this should be adapted to the actual server response returned by your APIs)
    if (!response.ok) {
        // handle the error related to the checkbox (this is just an example)
        setError("You don't have the permission to check this box");
        
        // stop the function here
        return;
    }

    // Second API call
    let response = await fetch("apiroute/second-call", { /* ... */ });

    if (!response.ok) {
        // handle second error related to the fields (also, this is just a minimal example)
        setError("There was some error in the submitted fields");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I expected. There is a scenario here , where you end up with 2 errors. Not even mentioning the extra work. You are only sequencing the process by using async await.

Comment: Of course, you should check for more then just "response.ok", I should have been more explicit about it, but in which situation would you end up with 2 errors? Maybe updating your answer with some code would help clarifying the difference between the solutions for other readers

Comment: @Drago96 thanks for your pseudo code. But my concern is one you stop the first api call, but the second api call gets successful and save other fields data into database. The end user will not aware of that as they can see the error "You don't have the permission to check this box" and we don't even have try catch here. Please correct me if am wrong, thanks

Comment: In this pseudo-code, the second API call won't be fired if the first one fails. If any error code is sent by the server, the "response.ok" flag will be false, the error will be set and the "return" will stop any further API call. It might be that you should check more than "response.ok" to be sure that the request failed, that actually depends on the API you're using, so some tests are needed.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put the second call to the api inside of .then after the first api call. This way, if the first api fails, 1 error will appear and the client will go after resolving that. Otherwise if you try to call them separately, if the first one fails, it goes to the second one and if that fails too, there will be two errors to be shown to the client, which does not sound user-friendly.

Comment: This is nice, probably might be clearer to do it with async-await https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @Drago96 Of course async-await should be used in almost all cases of api calls. It makes a sequence for the calls. But what I'm suggesting is to make the second call dependent on the first call. With only using async-await we can't achieve that. Plus if it's for example a network error, It's gonna take like 10 seconds for the first api to give back the error, and then it takes another 10s to get back the second one. Which will be kind of a mess.

Comment: @SobhanJahanmard I got your point and based the above reply, we cannot use the async/await to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Ok, I'll expand what I meant with async-await with another answer